# Update WCF endpoint nodes in web.config using Powershell

Tags: c#, wcf, powershell, config

I need to update a set of WCF endpoints in our web.config and I'd like to add this as a command in a powershell script. Below is the script as I currently have it written. It will update the `ConnectionString` nodes just fine, however it cannot find any of the `value` nodes in the `Periscope.My.MySettings` section.

The loop will execute a specific number of times, however the value in the `$_.value` variable is empty every time.

**web.config**

```
<applicationSettings>
  <Periscope.My.MySettings>
    <setting name="Periscope_periscopeSearch_Service1" serializeAs="String">
      <value>http://inside.com/periscopeSearch/Service1.asmx</value>
    </setting>
    <setting name="Periscope_periscopeRetrieveRelationships_Service1" serializeAs="String">
      <value>http://inside.com/periscopeRetrieveRelationships/Service1.asmx</value>
    </setting>
    <setting name="Periscope_periscopeRetrieveProducers_Service1" serializeAs="String">
      <value>http://inside.com/periscopeRetrieveProducers/Service1.asmx</value>
    </setting>
    <setting name="Periscope_periscopeRetrieveMasterSubs_Service1" serializeAs="String">
      <value>http://inside.com/periscopeRetrieveMasterSubs/Service1.asmx</value>
    </setting>
    <setting name="Periscope_periscopeRetrieveGeneral_Service1" serializeAs="String">
      <value>http://inside.com/periscopeRetrieveGeneral/Service1.asmx</value>
    </setting>
    <setting name="Periscope_periscopeRetrieveComments_Service1" serializeAs="String">
      <value>http://inside.com/periscopeRetrieveComments/Service1.asmx</value>
    </setting>
    <setting name="Periscope_periscopeRetrieveProfiles_Service1" serializeAs="String">
      <value>http://inside.com/periscopeRetrieveProfiles/Service1.asmx</value>
    </setting>
  </Periscope.My.MySettings>
</applicationSettings>
```

**Powershell**

```
$dir = Get-ChildItem $directory -Recurse 
$config = $dir  | where {$_.extension -eq ".config"}

#generated config connection strings
foreach($file in $config)
{   
    Write-Host "Updating $file" -ForegroundColor Green    
    $doc = [xml](Get-Content $file.FullName)

    #THIS WORKS FINE
    if($doc.configuration.connectionStrings){
        $doc.configuration.connectionStrings.add |%{
            if($_.connectionString.ToLower() -match $oldDb.ToLower()){
                $_.connectionString = $_.connectionString.ToLower().replace($oldDb.ToLower(), $newDb)
            }
        }
    }

    #THE $_.value VARIABLE IS EMPTY EVERY TIME
    $doc.configuration.applicationSettings.Periscope.My.MySettings.add | foreach {
        if($_.value){
            $tempString = $_.value.ToLower()
            if($tempString -match $oldDb.ToLower()){
                $_.value = $tempString.replace($oldDb, $newDb)
            }
            elseif($tempString -match $oldDomain.ToLower()){
                $_.value = $tempString.replace($oldDomain.ToLower(), $newDomain)
            }
        }   
    }

    $doc.Save($file.FullName) 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have XML elements with periods (`Periscope.My.MySettings`), so you must escape them with `'` so xml correctly treats it as a single element, not 3 separate elements. You also need to change `add` to `setting`, because `add` does not exist in case of settings, it only exists in connection strings.

You should change your code like this:

```
$doc.configuration.applicationSettings.'Periscope.My.MySettings'.setting | foreach {
    # Your other code
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same blank results, unfortunately

Comment: @NealR You also need to change `add` to `settings`. See updated answer

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks, still getting a handle on the powershell syntax/conventions. This worked :)